# How to ignore siblings elements while searching in XPATH?

Tags: html, xpath

The following DIV is on a page and I want to find an element by C1102W:

```
<div class="product-sku hidden-xs">
<span>Item #: </span>
C1102W            </div>
```

I have tried the query:

```
$x("//*[normalize-space()='C1102W']")
```

However, because of the span, it does not return the correct element, because it is looking for something like "Item #: C1102W". The following query returns too many results:

```
$x("//*[contains(., 'C1102W')]")
```

Is there anyway to query "Give me the element that contains only C1102W, ignoring the span or any other siblings"?

EDIT: Solution that worked for me.

```
//text()[normalize-space() = 'C1102W']/..
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//div[ends-with(normalize-space(), 'C1102W')]
```

will return only those `div` elements whose space-normalized string value ends with `'C1102W'`.